# How to pass a string variable as a shell script argument?

Tags: java, jsp, shell, process, runtime.exec

I have string variables as

```
String var1 = "I am"
String var2 = "here"
String cmd = ("sh /path/shell.sh \""+var1+"\" \""+var2);
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(cmd);
```

But when I execute `echo $1 $2` from my shell script, I get the output as `I am`. Why doesn't the quotes work?

Comment: You forgot a closing `quote(")` after var2.

Comment: *"from JAVA"* 1) No need to include the major tag in titles. 2) It is spelled 'Java', not 'JAVA'. 3) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  **Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.**

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call the command as follows:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("sh", "/path/shell.sh", var1, var2);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    //...
}
//...
scan.close();
process.destroy();
```

You'll probably want to wrap that in a `try-catch` block too.